# Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to run the following code in RStudio v0.99

```
plot.data <- data.frame(pca$x[, 1:2]) 
g <- ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) + geom_point(colour=?alpha("steelblue", 0.5), size=4) + geom_text(label=1:102, colour="darkgrey", hjust=1.5) + theme_bw() 
print(g)
```

Returns the following error:

```
Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: colour, size
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show some of your data, `dput(droplevels(head(plot.data)))`. Also I don't think you want the `?` in `colour = ?alpha`... that might be the entire problem.

Comment: Try changing `label=seq(nrow(pca$x))`

Comment: @Gregor If I remove the "?" and have "colour = alpha" I get the error: "could not find function 'alph'".

Comment: @user20650 made suggested update; no dice.

Comment: Result of {dput(droplevels(head(plot.data)))} :
structure(list(PC1 = c(-13564.50441795, -16281.5314556276, -16281.5314556276, 
41397.6917612853, -16273.0097697289, 21002.8853376488), PC2 = c(-548.227255594305, 
-779.759833099391, -779.759833099391, -5201.25043499976, -777.497877611026, 
8086.49523440387)), .Names = c("PC1", "PC2"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: How many rows does `pca$x` have?

Comment: I can reproduce the error if i have fewer / more labels than there are  x&y points ... eg `pca <- prcomp(USArrests, scale. = T) ; plot.data <- data.frame(pca$x[, 1:2]) ; 
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) + 
  geom_text(label=seq(nrow(pca$x))[-1], colour="darkgrey")` . Then try it after removing the `[-1]`. I would double check the hard coded numbers

Comment: @user20650 there are (6) rows

Comment: 6 rows but 102 labels??

Comment: `alpha` is in the `scales` package, so try either `library(scales)` before your code or `colour = scales::alpha(...`

Comment: And edit the `dput` from you comment into your question.

Comment: @Gregor used "colour = scales::alpha(..."

Comment: @user20650 updated to 6 labels.  With both your and Gregor's edits this code ran successfully.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question was to change `colour=?alpha` to `colour=scales::alpha` and update the number of labels to match the number of rows in the data set. It ended up looking like this:

```
plot.data <- data.frame(pca$x[, 1:2]) 
g <- ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) + geom_point(colour=scales::alpha("steelblue", 0.5), size=4) + geom_text(label=1:6, colour="darkgrey", hjust=1.5) + theme_bw() 
print(g)
```

Thanks to @Gregor & @user20650 for supplying the answer.